# Getting Error of type mismatch in vb6

Tags: sql, oracle, vb6

I am using this code and getting error of type mismatch, runtime error '13'
Error is in line which is marked below, And specifically error is due to where condition (`prereq.paid=" + rs1!paid + " "`)  in query...

```
rs1.Open "select name,nposts,postad.paid as paid from ad,post,postad where ad.adid = " +
         cmbAdno.Text +
         " and ad.adid=postad.adid and postad.pid=post.pid ", con, adOpenDynamic, 
         adLockOptimistic

While Not rs1.EOF
  cmbTitle.AddItem (rs1!Name)    
  rs1.MoveNext
Wend

rs1.MoveFirst

cmbTitle.Text = rs1!Name
txtNposts.Text = rs1!nposts

If IsNumeric(rs1!paid) Then
  MsgBox (rs1!paid + 1)
End If

**rs2.Open "select title from postad,prereq where postad.paid = prereq.paid and prereq.paid=" + 
        rs1!paid + " ", con, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic**

While Not rs2.EOF
  lstPrereq.AddItem (rs2!Title)
  rs2.MoveNext
Wend

rs2.Close

rs1.Close
```

Answer (score 5):

Whew, that code needs some work!

The plus operators are the culprit here though.  You can easily verify this with a small test case.

```
Dim ADO_Field_Value As Variant
Dim S As String

ADO_Field_Value = True

On Error Resume Next
S = "text" + ADO_Field_Value + ""
If Err Then MsgBox "Plus failed, err " & CStr(Err)
Err.Clear
S = "text" & ADO_Field_Value & ""
If Err Then MsgBox "Amp failed, err " & CStr(Err)
```

If you run this the "+" yields an error 13 while the "&" works as expected.

Use the ampersand for concatenation.  The plus only sorta, kinda works for backward compatibility with ancient times.  Using it requires the compiler to guess at your intent in order to resolve the soft overloading of the operator.

Your "Null hack" concatenting an empty String to the .Value isn't particularly clever.  If rs1 has a Null there you end up with a SQL syntax error, unless you use "+" which gets you an error 94.

ADO Field values are safer to access by explicitly using .Value instead of letting the compiler guess you want the default property of the Field.  While/Wend is obsolete, and what's with those extraneous parentheses?

You are asking the compiler to do things it probably shouldn't in this code.

Answer (score 0):

is rs1!paid a boolean in the database? if so, maybe there is an issue with the concat to make the query string.
In the old days, when i used VB6 i never accessed fields like that. I used something like rstRecordSet.Fields(0) or rstRecordSet.Fields("field1") but that should not be the problem if the field exists.
Create a string before and pass it the concatenation of the query and verify that it gets filled.

Also, you have "...postad.paid as paid...", why? you dont need to rename the field there...